# JTable Clickable Header in swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello i have a hard time solving this puzzle. professor gave the code and told us to change it to make column head clickable.can anyone change it for me.? wasted almost 4 hours :( not too great in java swings below is the code... 
below is the code :

```
package academic.emailClient.view;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import academic.emailClient.model.Message;
import academic.emailClient.view.entities.MessageView;

public class MailBox extends JFrame {


JTable tableinbox;

 private final int MAILBOX_FRAME_WIDTH = 1080; 
 private final int MAILBOX_FRAME_HEIGHT = 650; 
 static final boolean VISIBLE = true;

public MailBox() {
    Object[] columnNamesinbox = { "Boolean", "Sender", "Subject", "Body" };
    Object[][] datainbox = {
            { false, "5@gmail.com", "D", "T" },
            { false, "r@gmail.com", "projhsdject work", "I " },
            { false, "r.@ymail.com", "Job Placement","Iut that" },
            { true, "yam@gmail.com", "s1", "as" }
            };

    DefaultTableModel modelinbox = new DefaultTableModel(datainbox,
            columnNamesinbox);
    tableinbox = new JTable(modelinbox) {

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int columninbox) {
            switch (columninbox) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 1:
                return String.class;
            case 2:
                return String.class;
            case 3:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return Boolean.class;
            }
        }
    };




    tableinbox.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    tableinbox.setGridColor(new Color(0,128,0));
    JTableHeader inboxheader = tableinbox.getTableHeader();
    inboxheader.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    inboxheader.setForeground(Color.white);

}


public int getMesssagesCount(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public int GetCheckedItemsNumber(int i) {
    return 0;
}

public Object[][] GetCheckedItems() {

    return GetCheckedItems();
}

public Object[][] GetMail() {
    return GetMail();
}

public Object[][] OrderByDate() {

    return OrderByDate();
}

public Object[][] OrderBySender() {
    return OrderBySender();
}

public Object[][] OrderBySubject() {
    return OrderBySubject();
}

public JTable getMailBox() {
    return tableinbox;
}


public void run() {

    JFrame MailBoxFrame = new JFrame();

    MailBoxFrame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(MAILBOX_FRAME_WIDTH, MAILBOX_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    MailBoxFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(MAILBOX_FRAME_WIDTH, MAILBOX_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    MailBoxFrame.setBounds(0, 0, MAILBOX_FRAME_WIDTH, MAILBOX_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    MailBoxFrame.setVisible(VISIBLE);
    MailBoxFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

}
```

Comment: See [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html). Also, follow Java naming conventions. `MailBoxFrame` - variable names should not start with an upper case character. `MAILBOX_FRAME_WIDTH` - only "static final" variables should be completely upper cased.

Comment: and int i = inboxheader.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint()); is rest for success,

Answer (score 1):

> professor gave the code and told us to change it to make column head clickable

See [`JTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoCreateRowSorter%28boolean%29).  E.G. This is what you might see after clicking the `Cat.` column header. the small upwards pointing arrow indicates the table is sorted on that column.

[image: Clickable table header]

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to sort your table by clicking the columnheaders, than you  simply have to create your own table model and overwrite the get column class function eg.

```
public class TableViewModel extends AbstractTableModel{

@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass( int column ) {
    switch(column) {
        case 0:
            return String.class;
        case 1:
            return String.class;
```

.
.
.

and after that bind your JTable with that tablemodel and sorter by

```
TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(<YOURJTABLE>.getModel());
```

.setRowSorter( sorter );